# MediaRSS parsing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rss

I'm trying to read the Flickr feed in order to parse the images. However, the images are in the media:thumbnail tag. Where would I begin to make a mediaRSS parser? Does anyone have an example?

Comment: Are you using a library or just JavaScript? Also, why not use Flickr's JSON API instead of XML. JavaScript understands JSON natively, so no parsing needed there. You get an object out it straightaway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). As far as i know Flickr provides a JSON feed.

Here is an example from a current project using jQuery and xml:

```
$("#loading").show();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/path",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
        $("#news_list").append('<p>Content</p>');
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
}
```

**Works awesome!**
 You only have to change the datatype to `json`.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you have further questions feel free to ask.